# Infineon XMC4200 alternative pin function for I2C using XMClib

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, cortex-m4

Since i'm unable to post on the infineon XMC forum any more i will try to find help on this forum.

I'm working on my first I2C code with the XMC4200 hexagon kit. I'm using Dave4 with the XMCLib.
I'm trying to use I2C with a PCA9865, the standard address is 0x40(i tested this with a I2C scanner code).
The problem i have now: there is no ACK coming back from the PCA9865.
My first question is:
According to the XMC datasheet, a I2C addres should be shifted 1 position to the left(for the read write bit) or am i wrong at this one? I this is correct is should use the address 0x80, right? 
My second question:
Since i have no scope, i'm unable to check if there is really an I2C signal coming from the pins i'm using.
I'm very unsure about the alternative function/pins i choose to work with.
I will post my code(I2C only) below, could somebody verify if this is correct for the XMC4200?
Thanks to everyone!

```
#include <xmc_i2c.h>
#define PIN_SDA P0_4
#define PIN_SCL P0_5

    /*I2C settings*/

XMC_USIC_CH_t *i2c = XMC_I2C1_CH0;
XMC_I2C_CH_CONFIG_t i2c_cfg =
{
        .baudrate = 100000U,
};

    /* I2C init*/
XMC_I2C_CH_Init(i2c, &i2c_cfg);
XMC_I2C_CH_SetInputSource(i2c, XMC_I2C_CH_INPUT_SDA, USIC1_C0_DX0_P0_4); /*eerst USIC1_C0_DX0_P0_4*/
XMC_I2C_CH_SetInputSource(i2c, XMC_I2C_CH_INPUT_SCL, USIC1_C0_DX0_P0_5); /*eerst USIC1_C0_DX0_P0_5*/
XMC_I2C_CH_Start(i2c);


    /*config pins I2C*/
XMC_GPIO_CONFIG_t   config_SDA;
config_SDA.mode = XMC_GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OPEN_DRAIN_ALT2;
config_SDA.output_strength = XMC_GPIO_OUTPUT_STRENGTH_MEDIUM;
config_SDA.output_level = XMC_GPIO_OUTPUT_LEVEL_HIGH;
XMC_GPIO_Init(PIN_SDA, &config_SDA);

XMC_GPIO_CONFIG_t   config_SCL;
config_SCL.mode = XMC_GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OPEN_DRAIN_ALT2;
config_SCL.output_strength = XMC_GPIO_OUTPUT_STRENGTH_MEDIUM;
config_SCL.output_level = XMC_GPIO_OUTPUT_LEVEL_HIGH;
XMC_GPIO_Init(PIN_SCL, &config_SCL);

    /*I2C COMMUNICATION*/
/*Address(addr) should reserve an additional bit at the LSB for read/write indication. For example, address 0x05 should be provided as 0x0a.*/
#define PCA9865_ADDRES (0x40)

XMC_I2C_CH_MasterStart(i2c, PCA9865_ADDRES, XMC_I2C_CH_CMD_WRITE);
while((XMC_I2C_CH_GetStatusFlag(i2c) & XMC_I2C_CH_STATUS_FLAG_ACK_RECEIVED) == 0U)
{
    /*wait for ack*/
}

XMC_I2C_CH_ClearStatusFlag(i2c, XMC_I2C_CH_STATUS_FLAG_ACK_RECEIVED);
```

Comment: If the 7 bit address is 0x40, you will indeed use 0x80 for a write, 0x81 for a read. I don't know if your scanner returns a 7 bit address.

Comment: I was using the wrong pins( or didn't configure ok ) it wen't fine with other pins. Indeed i had to use 0x80. Read and write bit are set by the I2C function(I2C_MasterWrite....).